# How to specifiy TOC levels for RMarkdown to powerpoint?

Tags: r, markdown, powerpoint

I only want the top heading level to show in the table of contents slide. When I add `toc_depth: 1` I get the error below. How can I customize this?

```
title: "Test Site Report"
subtitle: "Supplement to the Provincial Report"

output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
    toc: true
       toc_depth: 1
```

Produces error `Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) :  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 9, column 17 Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous> Execution halted`

Comment: `toc` and `toc_depth` are both arguments to `powerpoint_presentation`, so they should have the same indentation.

Answer (score 0):

In YAML, indentation indicates that an indented entry is part of the less indented entry before it.  R Markdown uses this to set arguments to functions.

So the `output:` entry says that the `powerpoint_presentation` is a function that defines the output format. `toc` and `toc_depth` are both arguments to `powerpoint_presentation`, so they should have the same indentation.

You get the syntax error because it sort of looks like `toc_depth: 1` is part of `toc: true`, but `toc: true` isn't in the right form for a container.